# Ember Mirage Fake API test with Postman

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli-mirage

I have my mirage setup which returns data on my defined models, for example if I call /api/users: it returns me all the fake users I need. If I take the same call and test it on Postman, it returns nothing? I thought mirage is acting like a fake API end point server and testing it with Postman will work. Am I missing anything here?

Comment: How/where are you using Postman? If it’s in a test env, I think that the default is that mirage is not active at all. This is configurable.

Comment: I am using Postman as an add on to chrome. just trying to issue the get request I have defined in mirage.

Comment: Cool, I think the answer jelhan gave below will help you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mirage is only intercepting AJAX and fetch requests in the current browser window. It's using [pretender library](https://github.com/pretenderjs/pretender) therefor, which replaces the native XMLHttpRequest object to achieve that one. This is not affecting any other browser window or addon. Therefore you can't query the mock API using Postman or any other client outside of current window. For the same reason you can't debug the requests in network tab of developer tools. However Mirage could be [configured to log intercepted requests to console](http://www.ember-cli-mirage.com/docs/v0.4.x/configuration/#logging).